# Required_if com mais de um field no Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Eu tenho a seguinte situação: Quero que um campo seja obrigatório apenas se os outros dois forem `null`, se um dos outros dois não for `null` esse campo já deixa de ser obrigatório.

Pensei em usar o `required_if`, porem creio que só pode declarar um campo e vários valores, mas não mais de um campo.

O código está assim:

```
'signature-one'=>'required_if:signature-two,null|required_if:signature-three,null|integer',
'signature-two'=>'nullable|sometimes|integer',
'signature-three'=>'nullable|sometimes|integer',
```

no jeitos que está o campo signature-one vai ser obrigatório mesmo que um dos outros dois seja `null`, e eu queria que fosse obrigatório apenas se os dois fossem `null`. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: e ai a solução foi o que precisava?

Comment: Foi sim cara, muito obg. Olhei a documentação, mas não sou mt bom em ingles ai dexei esse tipo de validação passar. vlw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O teste para esse tipo é com [***required_without_all***](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-required-without-all), onde tradução diz:

> O campo em validação deve estar presente e não vazio somente quando
>   todos os outros campos especificados não estiverem presentes.

***Validação:***

```
'signature-one'=>'required_without_all:signature-two,signature-three',
'signature-two'=>'nullable|sometimes|integer',
'signature-three'=>'nullable|sometimes|integer',
```

<sup>***Referencias:***</sup>

- [Laravel: Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation)
- [Laravel: required_without_all](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-required-without-all)